# Filter Products in Category Page Depending on Product's Attributes Added in Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I am trying to filter products in a specific product category page.

What I am trying to filter:
If a product is added to cart, category should display products only with the same attribute value.

For example: if an item with attribute name "Color" & attribute value "blue" is added to cart, only products with same value should be displayed.

I've reached a point where filtering alone is working. But when it comes to cart attributes. It returns empty category.

Here is my code:

```
// Check for products in Cart Attributes

function is_attr_in_cart( $attribute_slug_term ){
    $found = false; // Initializing
    $attribute = 'pa_cpu-generation';

    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) 
        return $found; // Exit
    else {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
                $cart_item_attribute = $cart_item['data']->get_attribute( $attribute );

                if ( $cart_item_attribute == '11th Generation' ) {
                    // Flag becomes true
                    $found = true;
                    break;
                }
                }
            }
        return $found; 
}

// Product Category Filtering

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'shop_only_builder_products', 10, 2 );

function shop_only_builder_products( $tax_query, $query ) {
  if ( is_attr_in_cart() == true ) {
    $params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 99,
    'post_type'      => array('product'),
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy'        => 'pa_cpu-generation',
        'field'           => 'slug',
        'terms'           =>  array( '11th Generation', '12th Generation' ),
        'operator'        => 'IN',
        )
      ) 
        );
    
        return $params;
    
    }
 }
}
```

Apologies for this mess.
In case you have any suggestions I would be at least grateful. Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: You can't add a whole query to the meta_query.  Which is what `woocommerce_product_query_meta_query` is filtering... just the meta_query.

Comment: You're correct! Replacing 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query' to 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query' did the job for attribute filtering.

Comment: @newbie Do not include answers in your original question, but effectively post them as an answer to your question. This way you can mark your question as solved afterwards